# Spritebatch doesn't work

Tags: drawing, monogame

in developing of my game using Monogame, i want to put in pause the game with a button in the upper right of screen... but when the others elements are drawing only the pauseImage doesn't displayed.
I put here the code of Draw() function:

SBatch.Begin();

```
            SBatch.Draw(PauseImage,new Vector2(1024,50), Color.White);

            if (_isPaused)
            {
                SBatch.Draw(ResumeImage, new Vector2(500, 300), Color.White);
                SBatch.Draw(QuitImage,new Vector2(600,300),Color.White);
            }
            SBatch.Draw(_castel.Image, _castel.PosCastle, Color.White);


            SBatch.DrawString(LineFont, _life + "/1000", _castel.PosLife, Color.Black);
            SBatch.DrawString(LineFont, "Score:" + _score, new Vector2(_castel.PosLife.X,_castel.PosLife.Y+50), Color.Black);


            SBatch.End();


            foreach (EnemyUnit t in _enemyUnits)
            {
                t.AnimatedSprite.Draw(SBatch, t.Pos);
                if (_mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && t.Area.Limit(_mouseState))
                {
                    float temp;
                    temp = t.Pos.Y;
                    t.Pos.Y -= 470;
                    MouseAttack.Draw(SBatch, t.Pos);
                    t.Pos.Y = temp;
                }
            }


            SBatch.End();
        }

        base.Draw(gameTime);
```

The image is a normal png Load in a Texture2D object.

Comment: Why do you call SBatch.End() twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the part where you draw the pauseImage to the end of the code, so it's drawn last and on top of everything else. Then remove the first `SBatch.End()` from your code.

```
foreach (EnemyUnit t in _enemyUnits)
{
    t.AnimatedSprite.Draw(SBatch, t.Pos);
    if (_mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && t.Area.Limit(_mouseState))
    {
        float temp;
        temp = t.Pos.Y;
        t.Pos.Y -= 470;
        MouseAttack.Draw(SBatch, t.Pos);
        t.Pos.Y = temp;
    }
}

if (_isPaused)
{
    SBatch.Draw(ResumeImage, new Vector2(500, 300), Color.White);
    SBatch.Draw(QuitImage,new Vector2(600,300),Color.White);
}

SBatch.End();
```